# Links not working in unordered list

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have a weird problem where my links work fine on one page or fail to do so on another. Here is my code for the non-working page:

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <a href="frontPage.html"><header>
        <img src="img/MOBILAX-LOGO.png" height="100" alt="logo">
        <h1>MOBI &amp; LAX</h1>
        <p>CELLULAR REPAIR CENTER</p>
            </header></a>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">ABOUT US</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">SERVICES</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">IPHONE REPAIR</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">BLOG</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">CONTACTS</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

And the code for the working page:

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <a href="frontPage.html"><header>
        <img src="img/MOBILAX-LOGO.png" height="100" alt="logo">
        <h1>MOBI &amp; LAX</h1>
        <p>CELLULAR REPAIR CENTER</p>
            </header></a>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a class="activeLink" href="side2.html">ABOUT US</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">SERVICES</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">IPHONE REPAIR</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">BLOG</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">CONTACTS</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

I am able to see the links fine, but they are not clickable.

Here is the CSS for the nav, ul and wrapper:

```
nav {
background-color: #2a2a2a;
width: 50%;
height: 200px;
float: left;
}
nav ul {
list-style: none;
height: 200px;
}
nav ul li {
float: left;
margin-top: 86px;
margin-left: 25px;
}
nav a {
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
}
nav a:hover {
color: #f25e44;
}
.activeLink {
color: #f25e44;
}
#wrapper {
width: 1400px;
/*border: 1px solid black;*/
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
box-shadow: 10px 5px 5px 10px #888888;
}
```

EDIT: I figured out the issue. I had a div overlapping my ul.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/z1b750t4/)

Comment: I tried the first one and it is working? define NOT WORKING?

Comment: Sorry, i should have defined "not working" more precisely. The problem is that i am not getting a cursor change when i hover over the link, and it doesn't activate the hover effect specified in the CSS, while it does so on the second page. I am aware that the links do not lead anywhere.

Comment: The css is working too, when I hover on the link I get this color `#f25e44`

Comment: I can post the entire code, since the issue must stem from other elements on the page. HTML: http://pastebin.com/LTXsz9de and the CSS: http://pastebin.com/W3gqArAZ

Answer (score 2):

The # would normally reference an anchor on your page and scroll there. Since you are just using the # it links to itself, so the page wouldn't reload, and would stay in the same place.
Your CSS also specifies not to decorate (underline) the hyperlinks, giving the impression that the link does nothing.

Edit: http://jsfiddle.net/2L3hL7w6/

I've added some CSS to highlight in red if a link has been visited - you'll see if you click on one of your links on the page it changes to red, showing the link does in fact work.

```
nav a:visited {
color: #ff0000;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i should have defined "not working" more precisely. The problem is that i am not getting a cursor change when i hover over the link, and it doesn't activate the hover effect specified in the CSS, while it does so on the second page. I am aware that the links do not lead anywhere.

Comment: Could this be a browser issue? The fiddle that you linked to highlights in a peach / orange colour and shows the cursor change

Comment: Thanks for the help, but when i apply that code it immediately turns all links red, without me activating them.

Comment: try adding in nav a:visited:hover {
color: #f25e44;
}

Answer (score 1):

All the links are the same in your example code. So when you once clicked one link....nothing more will happen since you are already there.

Comment: for clarification, in your address bar you might see something like: http://localhost:56963/# (notice the hash) and so you're already at that '#' page